# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis in UnionAll

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query which runs fine through sql developer but throws error while running in application:

```
"SELECT DECODE(STATE_ID, 7, 'INPROGRESS','NOT_INPROGRESS')STATUS "+
                          "FROM ((SELECT A.STATE_ID FROM DSP_SIM_INVENTORY_DTLS A, DSP_TRANSACTION_DTLS B "+
                          "WHERE A.IMSI = B.IMSI AND B.MSISDN_D = ? AND A.ORDER_ID = ? AND A.IMSI = ? "+
                          "UNION ALL"+
                          "SELECT C.STATE_ID FROM DSP_SIM_STC_DTLS C"+
                          "WHERE C.MSISDN_D = ? AND C.ORDER_ID = ? AND C.IMSI = ?) )"
```

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: You're missing spaces all over the place. Print out the query text when you have this sort of issue, you'll see it immediately.

Comment: Also: you don't need to put each select statement of a union between parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong space between the string and also a few () on more

```
"SELECT DECODE(STATE_ID, 7, 'INPROGRESS','NOT_INPROGRESS')STATUS "+
  " FROM ( (SELECT A.STATE_ID FROM DSP_SIM_INVENTORY_DTLS A, DSP_TRANSACTION_DTLS B "+
  " WHERE A.IMSI = B.IMSI AND B.MSISDN_D = ? AND A.ORDER_ID = ? AND A.IMSI = ? )"+
  " UNION ALL "+
  " ( SELECT C.STATE_ID FROM DSP_SIM_STC_DTLS C "+
  " WHERE C.MSISDN_D = ? AND C.ORDER_ID = ? AND C.IMSI = ?) ) "
```

Comment: I added the paranthesis for the individual select between union all because I was getting, ORA--00928, missing select keyword.

Comment: I have update the answer with  parenthesis for individual select.. let me know if work or there are errors ..